# How to access multiple types of Models inside Collection?

Tags: collections, model, backbone.js

I have two different models inside a collection, how do I access them inside a view? The questions has 2 parts, please let me know if you are not clear with the questions.

**Part 1**

Model 1

```
Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({
     initialize:function(){
         console.log("The model 'Movie' initialized");
     }
});
```

Model 2

```
Songs = Backbone.Model.extend({
     initialize:function(){
          console.log("The model 'Songs' initialized");
     }
});
```

The instance created for these models are added to the collection as array as follows

```
var movie = new Movie({type:"movie",name:"Lord of the Rings",year:"2006"});
var songs = new Songs({type:"songs",name:"Rahna Thu", artist:"A R Rahman", album:"Delhi-6"});

var entertainment = new Backbone.Collection([movie,songs]);
```

Now, how do I access these models inside my view? To load these models and bind to a template? I do not know if I am correct but I did something like this

```
MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
    collection:entertainment,
    initialize:function(){
        $.each(this.collection.toJSON(),function(i,item){
            if(item.type=="songs"){
                alert("Song: "+item.name+" Artist: "+item.artist+" Album: "+item.album);
            }
        });
    }
});
var mainview = new MainView({el:$('body')});
```

Though I am getting the alert correctly, I need to know if this is the correct method to do it.

**2nd Part**

Now my second part of the question. What if these models just has the 'urlRoot'? How do I pre-fetch the model and fill up the collection?

I.e. In my second scenario my models are as follows

```
Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({
     urlRoot:"https://localhost:8080/entertainment/movies"
});
```

and

```
Songs = Backbone.Model.extend({
     urlRoot:"https://localhost:8080/entertainment/songs"
});
```

Now, how do I add these models to the collection and access them inside the view?

The actual solution, I am looking forward is to load multiple data like, a grid, chart and other server side data when the dashboard page is being loaded. Since all of this need to be filled on the page load, I thought of a solution like this. I am doing the right thing here? Or is there a better way to do it?

Sorry that the question is quite long, but really appreciate some expert advice here.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone actually is designed to have Model and Collection differently than you are. Models should be similar in structure data-oriented object, as collection should be aggregator for similar models.

Your app should look something like :

```
var Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    initialize: function() { console.log('movie initialized') });
});

var Song = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    initialize: function() { console.log('song initialized') });
});

var Movies = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
    model : Movie,
    url : 'https://localhost:8080/entertainment/movies'
    initialize: function() { console.log('movies collection initialized') });
});

var Songs = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
    model : Song,
    url : 'https://localhost:8080/entertainment/songs'
    initialize: function() { console.log('songs collection initialized') });
});

MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:function(){
        this.entertainment = {
            songs : new Songs(),
            movies : new Movies()
        };
        this.entertainment.songs.each( function(model) {  // Underscore method
             alert("Song: "+model.get('name')+" Artist ...");
        });
    }
});
```

You should not place different type of models in one collection, because you will break ( or you will create incorrect ) database API.